# Cypress open output occupies all the page, can't see the page itself

Tags: cypress

Running cypress 9.6.0, I accidentally dragged the output across the entire screen, and now I can't drag it back since it reduces the size of the window itself, not the UI of the tested page which is gone.

What I tried:

1. `Cypress.config('viewportWidth', 1280)`
2. `cy.viewport(600,600)`
3. uninstall and reinstall Cypress

Any ideas?
This feels like such a silly problem

[image]